# The orbit of a non zero vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Prove that given any non zero vectors $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $Av=w$.

(I don't know where to start. Any hints will be appreciated)

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Lucas! What have you tried? Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to phrase your question in a way more likely to elicit responses on here.

Comment: I don't know where to start. I'm thinking of trying it with the contradiction but it doesn't lead me anywhere. Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: Other ways to improve your question can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and I emphasize particularly the part which explains how to [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). For example, have you tried to prove existence of $A$ in any special cases, such as the special case $n=2$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $w$ is a scalar multiple of $v$, you could just let $A$ be a scalar matrix. That is, if $w=\lambda v$, then take $A=\lambda I$.

Otherwise $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, and take $\{v,w,b_3,\ldots,b_n\}$ to be some basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $P$ be the $n\times n$ matrix $[v\ w\ b_3\ \ldots\ b_n]$. Then take $$A=P\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}0&1&\\1&0&\\\hline&&I\end{array}\right]P^{-1}$$

Comment: Can you explain to me why the first column of the middle matrix is e2

Comment: @LucasHaobam So that we have
$$
Av 
= A(1\cdot v + 0 \cdot w + 0\cdot b_3 + \cdots + 0 \cdot b_n) 
\\ \qquad = 0 \cdot v + 1 \cdot w + 0 \cdot b_3 + \cdots + 0 \cdot b_n = v.
$$
In other words, we want to ensure that $APe_1 = Pe_2$.

Comment: @LucasHaobam That matrix in the middle acts to swap $e_1$ and $e_2$. That is, $Me_1=e_2$ and $Me_2=e_1$. So with $Av=PMP^{-1}v$, $P^{-1}$ turns $v$ into $e_1$, then $M$ turns that into $e_2$, then $P$ turns that into $w$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one fell swoop just by completing, on the one hand, $v$ to a basis, and, on the other hand, $w$ to a basis for $\Bbb R^n$.

Then the answer to the question will be yes if there exists an invertible matrix which sends the first basis to the second.  The answer is yes, namely the identity transformation expressed relative to the two bases, aka the change of basis matrix.